# octopus gem trying to write to slave instead of master

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.3, octopus

The following error is being generated on a slave server for a rails 3.2.18 application running gem "ar-octopus" over postgreSQL 9.3.5

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::SessionsController#create

PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
: UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at"
```

The `shards.yml` fiel is defined to its slave

```
octopus:
  replicated: true
  fully_replicated: true
  environments:
    - development
    - production
  development:
    shards:
      slave1:
        adapter: postgresql
        host: slave_1_ip_address
        database: app_development
        username: my_user
        password: my_password
```

and should nominally identify the master from the database.yml file

```
development:
#  adapter: postgresql
  adapter: postgis
  database: app_development
  username: my_user
  schema_search_path: public
```

You'll note that the adapter comes in both forms: as this application requires postgis, the master is defined with postgis, and I assume the slave ought to be as well as queries will require it.  Still, both forms have been tried and the error stays the same.

Why is octopus not doing what it purports to?

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out? I'm also facing UPDATEs being sent to replicas instead of the primary.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I think this was an issue with octopus for sometime. It seems fixed now. https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/472

Comment: good pickup! Not an easy thread to follow given time spans... worhtwhile to look back into now.